# Windows will not load - Conflict between Windows repair and Raid 1 array/driver?

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, raid-1, repair-install

I have a friend whose computer hangs when it tries to load Windows XP. It has worked fine until a couple weeks ago.

- *Dell Dimension (don't have model number right now)
- *Pentium 4
- *1 GB RAM
- *2 identical HDDs setup from the factory with RAID 1 (mirror)

I have used an ubuntu live CD to verify all the data seems to be intact on each drive. Everything seems to be fine until Windows XP boots, and the "waiting" bar runs for a few seconds, then BSOD with error 0x0000007E (possible driver issue).

I have tried to repair windows with the install disk, but the repair utility says that it cannot detect any Windows installs.

Is the RAID array keeping Windows repair from detecting the Windows install? Am I even barking up the right tree? I have tried removing each drive from the system and booting, but I get the same BSOD. I have tried to disable the array, but I get cryptic messages about possible data loss.

Are there other avenues I should explore?

Jeff S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XP disk you are using may not have the raid driver it needs, I would try to slip the mass storage drivers into the XP cd and see if it enables you to do a repair.

.
Use driver packs to slipstream "Mass storage" drivers into the XP CD.

Driver packs tutorial, read carefully.

http://forum.driverpacks.net/viewtopic.php?id=1449

Download software "Driverpacks Base"

http://driverpacks.net/downloads

You can install other driver packs besides the "Mass Storage", but this will bloat the size of the XP install to DVD size, The only driver packs I suggest to slipstream are

Mass Storage, Chipset, Lan, CPU

This will keep it a size to fit on a CD. If you want all the drivers slipstreamed it will require a DVD burner to make the DVD and a DVD drive on the target installation PC.

I don't change any of the default settings when using the software, just pick the driver packs you want to slipstream and create the ISO image.

If you use other customizing software for other reasons than drivers such as Nlite, use Nlite first then driver packs last or install problems will result. Only use DP to slip drivers, do not use Nlite for this task.

Start with clean unmodified Installation files when using DP for best results

Comment: Well, my friend took it to a repair shop instead. If they're not able to fix it, I will give it a shot. I decided to select yours as the best answer over all the other choices. :)

Comment: Let us know what the shop finds.